# Missing schools on college scorecard

Tags: collegescorecard

Does anybody know why are some schools not showing up on the College Scorecard (https://collegescorecard.ed.gov) recently released by the Obama administration? For example, why isn't Gateway Community & Technical College in Kentucky showing up?

Comment: Westpoint is not on there either.

Answer (score 4):

At the present time, the Scorecard site is limited to institutions that predominantly grant 2-year and/or 4-year degrees. The Department of Education is exploring whether and how to add predominantly less-than-two-year schools that offer associate’s or bachelor’s degree programs to the site in future iterations of Scorecard.

Comment: Note that while these schools are not displayed in the  https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/ search page, data including earnings data for some of these schools may be available by clicking the download all data link in the data page here https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/

Comment: may be available? pretty sure this is something that you should be aware of

Comment: The Department recently added institutions to the consumer site such that institutions that predominantly award certificates (PREDDEG=1) are included IF the highest degree awarded is at least an Associate's (HIGHDEG>=2 ) AND the institution offers an associate's or bachelor's degree (CIPxxASSOC>0 OR CIPxxBACHL>0)

Answer (score 2):

I believe Brian is correct, but also note that this criteria appears to be arbitrary and undocumented. One result is that only 6 of 13 community colleges in Colorado are included in the Scorecard.
http://mfeldstein.com/17-of-community-colleges-are-not-included-in-college-scorecard/